# Short intruduction to OOP basics

Tags: oop

Can somebody point me to good intruductions into OOP main paradigms, like inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation? I am looking for short article, about 2-3 pages, for very quick reading.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In`cap`su`la´tion
n. 1. (Physiol.) The process of becoming, or the state or condition of being, incapsulated; as, incapsulation of the ovum in the uterus.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: Umm... maybe " *En* capsulation"...

Comment: The Java Tutorial site covers this subject very well.  About one page per each of the core concepts of OOP.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just google for it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: -1: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers ; I agree this is an easily Google-able topic, but that shouldn't dissuade users from providing a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions from Alan Kay (he invented the term) on c2.com:

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKaysDefinitionOfObjectOriented

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKayOnMessaging

Which might not be the object-oriented you're looking for.

> The big idea is "messaging" - that is what the kernel ...
>    is all about ... The Japanese have a small word - ma - for "that which
>    is in between" - perhaps the nearest English equivalent is "interstitial".
>    The key in making great and growable systems is much more to design how its
>    modules communicate rather than what their internal properties and
>    behaviors should be.

Answer (score 0):

A very quickly reading cannot introduce you to the OOP paradigm. It's a very large topic and it's better that you study it with attention because it can determine how your code is structured.
I also suggest you to improve your knowledge of design patterns, when you'll correctly understand OOP.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly a niche topic. For a C#-angle on it take a look at MSDN's documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the [Simple English wiki article on OOP](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).